# what does shuffle and seed parameter in Keras image_gen.flow_from_directory() signify?

Tags: neural-network, keras, tensorflow, image-classification, training

```
image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=src_path_train,
    target_size=(100, 100),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset='training',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
```

What does shuffle in the code snippet mean? Does this indicate that the `flow_from_directory` function shuffles the images before loading them? if so, how does it help the training procedure?

Again, I'm reading an [article](https://studymachinelearning.com/keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow_from_directory/) where the shuffle setting is `True` for training and validation but `False` for testing. Why is this different for testing?

```
train_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=src_path_train,
    target_size=(100, 100),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset='training',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
valid_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=src_path_train,
    target_size=(100, 100),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset='validation',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=src_path_test,
    target_size=(100, 100),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=42
)
```

the above code snippet is taken from the [article](https://studymachinelearning.com/keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow_from_directory/) where the shuffle setting is True for training and validation but False for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `shuffle = True` your dataset will be randomly shuffled to avoid any overfitting in training. Passing samples in different orders makes the model more robust to overfitting. That's why during training it is advisable to turn on shuffling while during inference (validation/test), you only need to get the output, no training. Hence, no shuffling.

Even though everything is random here, you can still reproduce your result using the `seed` parameter. It will reproduce the same result every time. If you don't use seed, then at every run, your model will be different and you cannot reproduce the results.

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle leads to more representative learning. In any batch, there are more chances of different class examples than sampling done without shuffle .
Like in deck of cards, if you shuffle chances of same card number ocuuring together reduces .
So training is robust but I don’t think it has to relate to overfitting .